# Python not waiting for return function, and continuing without a response

Tags: python, tkinter, return

I have a function that saves files to the user's computer in Tkinter. I am trying to create a prompt for the user if they are trying to save a file that already exists, asking them if they'd like to overwrite the existing file, or not. I'm not going to include the whole code as it is 3000+ lines, but an example of what I'm trying to do:

`I understand os.path.save() is not valid, I'm using Shutil to copy an existing file from another location, this is just for example purposes.`

```
def overWritePrompt():
    promptFrame = tk.Frame(maniWin, bg=_blk)
    promptFrame.place(relx=.4,rely=.2,relheight=.1,relwidth=.2)

    promptHead = tk.Label(promptFrame, bg=_blk, fg=_wht, text="Overwrite existing route?")
    promptHead.place(relx=0,rely=0,relheight=.4,relwidth=1)
    
    promptYes = tk.Button(promptFrame, bg=_dgrn, fg=_wht, text="Yes", relief="sunken", activebackground=_dgrn, activeforeground=_wht, command=lambda:(selection(True)), borderwidth=0)
    promptYes.place(relx=.1,rely=.5,relheight=.4,relwidth=.35)
    
    promptNo = tk.Button(promptFrame, bg=_red, fg=_wht, text="No", relief="sunken", activebackground=_red, activeforeground=_wht, command=lambda:(selection(False)), borderwidth=0)
    promptNo.place(relx=.45,rely=.5,relheight=.4,relwidth=.35)

    def selection(response):
        promptFrame.destroy()
        return response

def saveFile(fileName):
    overwrite = False
    if os.path.exists(os.path.join(directory, fileName)):
        overwrite = overwritePrompt()
    if overwrite:
        os.path.remove(fileName)
        os.path.save(fileName) 
    else:
        os.path.save(fileName)
```

I expect this to display the prompt to the user and wait for a response before continuing to the saving portion, however it just immediately returns `None` for the overwrite bool, and continues on with the rest of the code.

Why isn't `overwrite = overwritePrompt()` waiting for `overWritePrompt()` to **return** before continuing?

I have tried adding **while** loops in different places to keep the code from moving on until the user inputs their answer, but that just freezes the app completely.

Comment: `overwritePrompt()` doesn't have a `return` statement so `overwrite` will always be `None`.

Comment: @Woodford there is another function inside `overwritePrompt()` that passes the return. That function is triggered by the Tkinter buttons. Is that not the correct way to do this?

Comment: `selection` returns a value, but that value isn't accessed within `overWritePrompt` anywhere, so it's essentially unused. And `overWritePrompt` doesn't return anything at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nested function `selection()` doesn't iteract with the outer function `overwritePrompt` at all so its `return` statement doesn't affect the value returned by the outer function. `selection()` is just a normal function like any other in that regard.

You could simplify the whole thing by using a built-in Tk message box:

```py
def saveFile(fileName):
    if os.path.exists(os.path.join(directory, fileName)):
        overwrite = tkinter.messagebox.askokcancel("Confirm", "Overwrite file?")
        if overwrite:
            os.path.remove(fileName)
    os.path.save(fileName)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, my tkinter doesn't seem to have the messagebox option for some reason. I did fix my problem, though. I have the save button function check if the file exists already, prompt the user, then pass that result to the actual save function, if that makes sense.

Comment: @BSIncorporated You have to import it separately. `tkinter.messagebox.askokcancel` won't work, but if you `from tkinter.messagebox import askokcancel` and then `overwrite = askokcancel(...)` it should work

Comment: Oh that makes sense, as I have quite a few prompt messages planned in the future, I will definitely use this to make my life easier. Thank you.

Comment: @BSIncorporated If you have a few prompts, it may make more sense to `import tkinter.messagebox as tkm` and then call the prompts with `tkm.askokaycancel`, `tkm.askyesno` etc. - there are quite a few in there!

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was having the "save" button, call on the `overWritePrompt()` **first**, then have the prompt check if the file exists, then pass the result of the user input to the `saveFile()` function.

```
def overWritePrompt(fileName):
    promptFrame = ""

    def clearPrompt():
        promptFrame.destroy()

    if os.path.exists(os.path.join(directory, fileName)):
        promptFrame = tk.Frame(maniWin, bg=_blk)
        promptFrame.place(relx=.4,rely=.2,relheight=.1,relwidth=.2)

        promptHead = tk.Label(promptFrame, bg=_blk, fg=_wht, text="Overwrite existing route?")
        promptHead.place(relx=0,rely=0,relheight=.4,relwidth=1)
        
        promptYes = tk.Button(promptFrame, bg=_dgrn, fg=_wht, text="Yes", relief="sunken", activebackground=_dgrn, activeforeground=_wht, command=lambda:(clearPrompt, saveFile(fileName, True)), borderwidth=0)
        promptYes.place(relx=.1,rely=.5,relheight=.4,relwidth=.35)
        
        promptNo = tk.Button(promptFrame, bg=_red, fg=_wht, text="No", relief="sunken", activebackground=_red, activeforeground=_wht, command=lambda:(clearPrompt, saveFile(fileName, False)), borderwidth=0)
        promptNo.place(relx=.45,rely=.5,relheight=.4,relwidth=.35)

    else: saveFile(fileName, False)

def saveFile(fileName, overwrite):
    if overwrite:
        os.path.remove(fileName)
        os.path.save(fileName) 
    else:
        os.path.save(fileName)
```